# Not able to extend timeout for beanstalk in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, centos, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, httpd.conf

I Need to extend timeout for my beanstalk in aws, I increased timeout in load balancer but still i am facing 502 error. So i tried to add httpd confing in .ebextensions folder below is provided file

```
# Managed by Elastic Beanstalk
PidFile run/httpd.pid

# Enable TCP keepclive
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 300

<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers        10
MinSpareThreads     250
MaxSpareThreads     250
ServerLimit         10
MaxClients          250
MaxRequestsPerChild 1000000
</IfModule>

Listen 80

Include conf.d/*.conf
Include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

CustomLog logs/access_log "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
TraceEnable off

LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
```

When i try to deploy this on beanstalk i started facing error:

> [Instance: i-0c436613676c84739] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...pd.conf AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: No MPM loaded. Failed to execute '/usr/sbin/apachectl -t -f /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/httpd/conf/httpd.conf' Failed to execute '/usr/sbin/apachectl -t -f /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/httpd/conf/httpd.conf'. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03_configure_proxy.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

I tried to add npm module in httpd.conf file but by doing this i am facing other issue and it never ends.
is there any correction required to do in this file?

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, that EC2/beanstalk image is missing this file:

`/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf`

Just create it with the following text:

```
# Select the MPM module which should be used by uncommenting exactly
# one of the following LoadModule lines.

# prefork MPM: Implements a non-threaded, pre-forking web server
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html
#
# NOTE: If enabling prefork, the httpd_graceful_shutdown SELinux
# boolean should be enabled, to allow graceful stop/shutdown.
#
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so

# worker MPM: Multi-Processing Module implementing a hybrid
# multi-threaded multi-process web server
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html
#
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so

# event MPM: A variant of the worker MPM with the goal of consuming
# threads only for connections with active processing
# See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html
#
#LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

then run `sudo systemctl restart httpd`